# OOP and eventListener in Lua (Corona SDK)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

My first steps in Corona SDK and first troubles. Trying to make two boxes which I can move by following [this](http://www.ludicroussoftware.com/blog/2011/07/06/simple-oop-with-inheritance-in-corona/) OOP tutorial, but this doesn't work. I have successfully created two boxes but only one is movable. When I try to move another one it doesn't moved but first one is moving. Guess there's problem with scopes but can't figure where is exactly.
Thank you for any help.

tile.lua source code:

```
module (..., package.seeall)


function new(initX, initY)

    local scrnWidth = display.stageWidth
local scrnHeight  = display.stageHeight
local squareSize = (scrnWidth*0.9)/4

   local tile = display.newRect( initY, initY, squareSize, squareSize )

   function move(direction)
       if direction == "left" then
            transition.moveTo(tile, {x = tile.x+squareSize,y = tile.y,time = 200})
    elseif direction == "right" then
            transition.moveTo(tile, {x = tile.x-squareSize,y = tile.y,time = 200})
    elseif direction == "up" then
            transition.moveTo(tile, {x = tile.x,y = tile.y-squareSize,time = 200})
    elseif direction == "down" then
            transition.moveTo(tile, {x = tile.x,y = tile.y+squareSize,time = 200})
    end
   end


function tile:touch(event)
        if event.phase == "began" then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( tile )
                beginX = event.x
                beginY = event.y
        end

        if event.phase == "ended"  then
                endX = event.x
                endY = event.y
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)

                checkSwipeDirection();
        end
    end

function checkSwipeDirection()

        xDistance =  math.abs(endX - beginX) -- math.abs will return the absolute, or non-negative value, of a given value. 
        yDistance =  math.abs(endY - beginY)

        if xDistance > yDistance then
                if beginX > endX then
                        move("right",tile)
                else 
                       move("left",tile)

                end
        else 
                if beginY > endY then
                        move("up",tile)
                else 
                        move("down",tile)
                end
        end

end

tile:addEventListener("touch", tile)
   return tile

end
```

and I create objects by using the following code in main.lua:

```
    local tileConst = require("tile")
    local tile1 = tileConst.new(100,100)
    local tile2 = tileConst.new(200,200)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `tile.lua` scene, declare a variable to hold touched sprite just below `module (..., package.seeall)`:

```
local touchedSprite -- my temporary sprite variable
```

Then assign the target sprite to the above variable inside the function as:

```
function tile:touch(event)
    touchedSprite = event.target -- Assigning target to variable
    ...
end
```

Now change the function `move` as follows:

```
function move(direction)
  if direction == "left" then
    transition.to(touchedSprite, {x = touchedSprite.x+squareSize,y = touchedSprite.y,time = 200})
  elseif direction == "right" then
    transition.to(touchedSprite, {x = touchedSprite.x-squareSize,y = touchedSprite.y,time = 200})
  elseif direction == "up" then
    transition.to(touchedSprite, {x = touchedSprite.x,y = touchedSprite.y-squareSize,time = 200})
  elseif direction == "down" then
    transition.to(touchedSprite, {x = touchedSprite.x,y = touchedSprite.y+squareSize,time = 200})
  end
end
```

Note that I've changed `transition.moveTo` to `transition.to` and your `transition tile` to `touchedSprite(target).`

Keep Coding.................. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution works like a charm but could you please provide some explanation? What exactly happens behind the screen? Thank you very much!

Comment: In your first code when you call 'tile', it will only awake the last created object since 'tile' has a local scope. Here, I have created a sprite variable with global scope throughout the 'tile.lua' page, and when touch happens to any object created by that page, I've assigned the target (that is event.target; means event occurred target) to the sprite variable, hence I can access the evoked object/sprite... :)

Comment: Hi, I still have problem with this code. Actually if I use it for single display.Object everything works fine, but when I use complex object, for example create dispay.Group and then insert inside few another object it became broken. For example group with square and digit moves only square.

Comment: I slightly changed the code using this tutorial http://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/09/29/tutorial-modular-classes-in-corona/ actually tile now in different module and different class and when I create tile I create group with square and digit (actually I try to write something like fifteen game). I will publish my code later on github but now I don't understand in general why it happens? I create few different objects (tables) inside every object independent eventListener assigned to group. Every object has its own scope, why it's being overlapped?

Comment: I can't correctly understand the new issue. But I think you have a problem with object overlapping and corresponding touch response issue. Just add `return true;` inside your `function tile:touch(event)` just above function `end` section.